# Probability of selecting distinct numbers in ascending order

Tags: probability, statistics

A relatively simple problem is stumping me on this :(

Given a set of 4 distinct numbers that can be chosen from [0-9], what is the probability that after selecting, the first two numbers would be in ascending order?

Here's my thinking so far:

- If we select 0 as our first, we have a 9/10 chance of choosing an appropriate second number
- If we select 1 as our first, we have an 8/10 chance of choosing an appropriate second number
- ...
- If we select 8 as our first, we only have a 1/10 chance of choosing an appropriate second number
- However if we select 9 as our first, we can't select anything greater

So the probability of selecting the first two numbers such that they are ascending should be:

P(1st selection) * P(2nd selection > 1st selection) * P(3rd selection that we don't care about) * P(4th selection that we don't care about) = 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 * 1/7 => 1/5040

I don't think I'm going about this problem the right way and my answer is completely off - I don't know how to handle what the probability of selecting the second number would be, since we could choose a great number like 0 for the first, or a bad one like 8 or 9 that would give us less choices.  Could someone explain this in a better way?

Comment: Do you understand what @did means with *symmetry*?

Comment: Erm not entirely... does this mean that the number of digits we select from makes no difference? say if we had a set of 100 numbers to select?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if things are still unclear.

Comment: Here's a way to understand the symmetry argument. Imagine a list of all ascending pairs: $(0,1), (0,2), \ldots, (8,9)$. If you reverse the order of the elements for each of those pairs, you get precisely the list of all descending pairs: $(1,0), (2,0), \ldots, (9,8)$. Each pair is accounted for either in the first list or the second, and the lists are of the same size. That is why the probability is $1/2$.

Comment: If you select two numbers, and I tell you the smaller one, what is the probability that the smaller one is the first and not the second of the two? Now if you find two numbers using some really complicated process, using the same process for each number, and I tell you the value of the smaller number, what's the probability that this was the first and not the second number?

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, the probability is $$\frac12.$$
Your approach yields
$$
\frac1{10}\cdot\frac99+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac89+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac79+\cdots+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac19=\frac1{10}\cdot\frac19\cdot\frac{9\cdot10}2=\frac12.
$$

Comment: Uhhh sorry, could you elaborate on how what you mean by symmetry and how you got those numbers?  With this approach does it mean that the number of digits makes no difference to the probability?  Say, for 100 numbers?

Comment: Symmetry: one can draw only two numbers since the others are irrelevant, then first number is greater than second number with the same probability that second number is greater than first number. QED. And yes the argument is valid for every collection instead of [0..9].

Comment: Those numbers: I started from your own computations and corrected them. This gives: "If we select 0 as our first, we have a 9/9 chance of choosing an appropriate second number.
If we select 1 as our first, we have an 8/9 chance of choosing an appropriate second number, and so on."

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ denote the event that the first two numbers are ascending and let $D$ denote the event that the first two numbers are descending. These events are disjoint and complements of eachother.

That means that $$P\left(A\right)+P\left(D\right)=1$$

Next to
that there is no reason to assume that $P\left(A\right)$ differs
from $P\left(D\right)$ so: $$P\left(A\right)=P\left(D\right)$$

(if you would change $0$ into $9$, $1$ into $8$ et cetera, then in essence nothing would change when it comes to the probabilities)

This
together leads to: $$P\left(A\right)=P\left(D\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$